# marker setIcon method strangely destroying marker object

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

See http://www.milebymile.com/main/highway-1777.html

Go to the right navigation bar and press on the campground + to see a selection of campgrounds. Click on the campground.

The first alert shows the getIcon url prior to the setIcon.  The second getIcon alert after the setIcon shows undefined because the marker appears now to be undefined.

The marker changes so the marker.setIcon is working but then after that fires. The corresponding marker can not be referenced again.

Have I done something wrong, or is this a bug?  Thanks in advance.

I am using Chrome Version 28.0.1500.44 beta-m.

Comment: Please post the problematic code, not just a link.

Comment: How are you trying to reference the marker again?

Comment: Have you tried a [google.maps.Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) instead of the deprecated google.maps.MarkerImage?  Not sure why that should matter, but you originally define the icon using a MarkerImage, but change it by setting the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not that the marker is being destroyed but that the marker.getIcon method no longer returns anything with a .url property.

So the second of these statements:

```
var old_icon_url = marker.getIcon().url;    
var new_icon_url = old_icon_url.replace(".png","_selected.png");
```

generates an error, and execution stops, so you don't see the alerts.

Error (in chrome):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined mapGenerate.js:111
```

Comment: Solution:

Thanks geocodezip. Your suggestion led me to the solution. I must define the icon with at least the url and the anchor. If you just pass the string into it, it creates the marker but does not maintain the url reference within the marker object anymore. Must be a bug or something. Anyway, by using the icon rather than the string reference the object remains intact.

marker.setIcon({
       url: "/images/mapIcons/"+ iconTypePOI +"_selected.png",
       anchor: google.maps.Point(7, 7)}
)